# How do I stop previous graphics from being redrawn in Java?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, graphics, jframe

I've been working on a game but messed something up and I can't figure what it is. I've simplified the code as much as possible in this example and it retains the same issue.

In this example, instead of the red square going upwards without leaving a trace, it leaves behind a red trace meaning the graphics are not being disposed of properly or the buffer strategy isn't working.

How do I make the red square not leave behind a trail?

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private boolean running = false;
    private int w = 1920/2, h = 1080/2, move = 300;
    private JFrame frame;
    private Thread thread;

    public game() {
         frame = new JFrame("Test");
         frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h));
         frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(w,h));
         frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(w,h));

         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setResizable(false);
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.add(this);
         frame.setVisible(true);
         start();
         setBackground(Color.black);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }    

    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            if(running) render();
        }
    }

    private void tick() {
        move--;
    }

    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(300, move, 50, 50);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }        

    public static void main(String[] args) { new game(); }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make the red square not leave behind a trail?

```
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(300, move, 50, 50);
```

Before you draw your red square you need to paint the entire background of your canvas.

```
g.setColor(...);
g.fillRect(...);
g.setColor(Color.red);
g.fillRect(300, move, 50, 50);
```